# Custom Button Control Doesn't Fire OnClick Event

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, overriding

This is my first attempt at creating a custom ASP.NET control and I've almost cracked it, but am falling at the final hurdle.

I've created a custom control which inherits from the Button class.  I've overridden the Render method because I want to add styling to the button, which obviously goes in the button's parent tag, thus precluding use of RenderContent or RenderChildren (as I understand it).  That part all works perfectly.

The problem is that in overriding the Render method I have obviously omitted something which is in the default Render method which allows the code in the OnClick method I've written to be fired.  If I simply comment out my overridden Render method and build the solution the button works perfectly (aside from the styling).  I have tried including `MyBase.Render(writer)` in my overridden Render method, but that appears to mess things up more, acting more as if my code in my Render method was in the RenderContent method.

So, I can either have the button look exactly as I want it but not function, or function perfectly but look wrong.  What's the missing piece of the puzzle?  What's missing from my overridden Render method, as follows:

```
    Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)

    Dim cssclass As String
    If ToggledOn = True Then
        cssclass = ToggledOnCssClass
    Else
        cssclass = ToggledOffCssClass
    End If

    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, cssclass)
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button)
    writer.Write(ToggledOn.ToString)
    writer.RenderEndTag()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem in the end by overriding the RenderBeginTag method rather than the Render method, as follows:

```
Public Overrides Sub RenderBeginTag(writer As HtmlTextWriter)

    Dim s As Style = New Style
    If ToggledOn = True Then
        s.CssClass = ToggledOnCssClass
    Else
        s.CssClass = ToggledOffCssClass
    End If

    s.AddAttributesToRender(writer)
    MyBase.RenderBeginTag(writer)

End Sub
```